# Puppeteer do not click in element

Tags: javascript, html, input, click, puppeteer

So 'm trying to make the way to see my grades easier.

I'm having some issues clicking on "Boletim", it does not work.

This is the button part of the website:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input id="btBoletim" onclick="btBoletim_click();" type="button" title="Emitir
             boletim"value="Emitir Boletim" class="form1" style="width:120px;cursor:pointer">
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

This is the line that i was trying to use:

```
  await page.click('[id="btBoletim"]');
```

I've already tried some other codes but they didn't worked too.

I think that is because the button open a  new window and I'm starting with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your elements are not ready when you are calling that script 
Insert bellow codes

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

or

```
await page.waitFor(100000)
```

to get load all of your elements

Thanks

Comment: I am bit late to get you. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets and the id key

```
 await page.click('#btBoletim');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery, if you're trying to simulate a click:

```
$("#btBoletim").click()
```

JQuery 3.2.1 Library: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

already made it work, just needed some time before clicking